# Extract a part of a TITLE and open it in a url?

Tags: javascript, imacros

I'm using iMacros.

Inspect Element show me this:

```
<a class="avatar " title="designperks's Instagram Profile" alt="designperks's Instagram Profile" href="/app/users/ig-1451494389/designperks/photos"
```

What I want to do is extract what's in TITLE until the apostrophe and open it in instagram.com, in this example it's `designperks` here is what I came up with:

```
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 2
TAB T=1
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=A ATTR=TITLE:* EXTRACT=TITLE
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; s.split(\"'\",\"\"); ")
SET !EXTRACT NULL
SET !EXTRACT {{!VAR1}}
TAB OPEN
TAB T=2
URL GOTO=http://instagram.com/{{!VAR1}}
```

I'm almost done, but I know that there is a mistake here `(\"'\",\"\"); ")` and I can't figure it out.

Many thanks!

Comment: I don't think the tag Java is relevant

Comment: I notice the one quote at the start of `SET !VAR1 EVAL(“` is a curlyquote, rather than the straight ".  Does changing that fix it?

Comment: Removed the Java tag and changed the "

Answer (score 0):

you could use jQuery.

```
$().ready(function() {
    alert($(".avatar").attr("title"));  
);
```

But I'm not sure if that's 'imactos' relevant.

Comment: "Relevant"? What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

How could I always extract the 4th element in `HREF`?

```
HREF:/app/users/*/*/photos
```