# s.split with TITLE don't work?

Tags: javascript, imacros

I'm using iMacros.

I want to extract/split `designperks` from:

`title="designperks's Instagram Profile"`

So I'm using:

`SET !VAR1 EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; s.split(\"'\"); ")`

But that doesn't work, and it should, do you know why?

Many thanks!

Comment: `.split()` returns an array, and you just want the first item. Is the problem that you're not even getting the array, or just that you need to say `s.split(\"'\")[0];`?

Comment: @nnnnnn The problem is that `(\"'\"); ")` is supposed to pick up the text until the `'` but instead it picks up the whole `designperks's Instagram Profile`

Comment: You asked this question a few hours earlier here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25695022/24874

Comment: @DrewNoakes I asked to question again because my previous one is still unsolved.

Comment: [That's not how Stack Exchange works](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160902/144937).

Comment: @DrewNoakes I'm sorry, I'm still new, I thought that my question was "lost" in the amount of questions posted every minute, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

```
var title="designperks's Instagram Profile"; 
s= title.split("'"); 
console.log(s[0]) // required output
```

check this.

Comment: In a JavaScript console it work, but how can I put that in a iMacros? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
var macro;

macro ="CODE:";

macro +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=name:SOME_DIV EXTRACT=TXT"+"\n";

iimPlasy(macro)

text=iimGetLastExtract();

text=text.split(",")[0];

alert(text);
```

This could work if you edit it per your request.